# How to negate specific word in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with format: `keyword/page-XXX` (ending by **page-XXX**, it can empty)

**keyword** is any character. All character before slash is keyword. But keyword can have slash. And keyword can be **page-XXX**

**XXX** is any number

(**page-XXX** is paging)

I wanna use regex to get value of keyword. How to?

eg:

String is: **I-Like-PHP/page-123/page-456/page-789**
=> Value of keyword is **I-Like-PHP/page-123/page-456**

String is: **I-Like-PHP**
=> Value of keyword  **I-Like-PHP**

String is: **I-Like-PHP/**
=> Value of keyword  **I-Like-PHP/**
(have slash)

String is: **I-Like-PHP/page-123**
=> Value of keyword  **I-Like-PHP**

String is: **page-123**
=> Keyword is **page-123**

String is: **page-123/**
=> Keyword is **page-123/**

How to get it with regex only?

Comment: first value before first slash is always keyword ?

Comment: did you try stripslashes function in php. it can remove slashes

Comment: $arr = explode("/", $string);
$first = $arr[0];
explode returns an array and first part will be saved in array

Comment: Where is the problem having multiple regex applied? It can be even more efficient and is easier to read, later.

Comment: What do you mean? keyword is any character. All character before slash is keyword. But keyword can have slash. And keyword can be page-XXX And it require use regex only, not use PHP to parse the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex, which captures everything up to a trailing `/page-XXX` or end-of-line if there is no paging:

```
^(.*?)(?=\/page-\d+$|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fOBGp0/2)

Comment: Hi,**keyword** is any character. All character before slash is keyword. But keyword can have slash. And keyword cannot be **page-XXX**
Your regex still math if string is "page-123"

Comment: @GracePeterson you did not make that clear in your question. Could you please add such end cases to it.

Comment: @GracePeterson in your question, you state "I have a string with format: keyword/page-XXX" so how can it be just "page-123"?

Comment: @GracePeterson it seems you have changed the question so that keyword *can* be `page-XXX` in which case I think this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you need only keyword

```
$str = 'I-Like-PHP/page-123/page-456/page-789';
preg_match('([^/]+)',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);die;
```

this will give you only

```
I-Like-PHP
```

Comment: It require regex only :)

Comment: this is not regex ?

Comment: You're using PHP to replace page-XXX then get keyword. But I require use regex to math the keyword. And note that keyword can be page-XXX